# Is the sum of a series equal to the value of its integral?

Tags: calculus

If an improper series converges, so will it’s sum. Does that mean that the value of the sum is the same as the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

$$
\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}>\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=1.
$$